# Matlab, anonymous functions, making a piecewise function, how?

Tags: matlab

If I want to make a piecewise function where lets say $f(x) = x^2 +1$ at $1 \leq t \leq 2$ and zero elsewhere.  How can I make this possible using an anonymous function?  I wanted to invent y = @(t) ((t.^2 + 1)*(t>=1)&&(t<=2))  
But that obviously did not work out at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have works for scalar input, but I guess you want to make it for vectors, in that case you need to adjust it a bit:

```
y = @(t) ((t.^2 + 1).*(t>=1)&(t<=2))
```

Comment: Thx! It worked for one. But when I tried this input it is all zeros.                                                         t2 = -0.5:0.01:1;
x2 =@(t2) ((t2.^2-0.5).*((t2>=-0.5)&(t2<=1)));

y_b =@(t2) -3.0*x2(t2-2);
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(t2,y_b(t2))
xlabel('t2')
ylabel('y_b(t2)')
axis([1.5 3 -2 1])

Comment: @user1945925 Note that you evaluate `x2(t2-2)` which is all zero

Comment: Im not seeing it...when I write x2(t2-2) I want the graph to shift to the right by 2. Any recommendations?

Comment: You can just change the x values in the plot.

Comment: I thought I did by axis([1.5 3 -2 1])